# How to use nested loops to run ANOVAs with different predictors and outcomes

Tags: r, loops, anova

I have been trying to estimate multiple ANOVA's at the same time with a loop. But I want to loop through both multiple predictors and multiple outcomes. So I have been trying to do a nested loop.

```
#data
test<-structure(list(Alcohol = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Smoker = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
), CXMP = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0), CXDIAG = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Treatment = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), metformin_base = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), BMI = c(38.17, 34.14, 39.55, 49.68, 41.44, 
43.23, 41.65, 53.11, 45.04, 46.78, 52.42, 51.36, 60.7, 48.36, 
53.31, 43.29, 57.44, 53.44, 40.54, 41.2, 55.36, 33.95), Waist = c(120, 
118.5, 129.5, 144, 133.7, 121, 118.7, 139, 120.1, 131.5, 121.5, 
115, 160, 154.1, 147, 128, 134, 132.5, 118, 129, NA, NA), age = c(74.52977413, 
38.02327173, 41.08966461, 63.80013689, 22.12457221, 61.06502396, 
61.55509925, 32.47638604, 65.60438056, 68.6899384, 55.86584531, 
39.52908967, 55.69883641, 57.83709788, 52.98288843, 32.678987, 
63.43052704, 51.29637235, 52.11225188, 67.9945243, 66.7926078, 
38.80903491), charleston = c(5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L), FOOD_Fruit = c(1, 
1.5, 1, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, NA, 2, 0, 0, 2.5, 2, 2, 2, 3.5, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 2), FOOD_Vegetable = c(3, 3.5, 2, 2, NA, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 5, 5), exercisemin = c(0L, 
30L, 20L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 85L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 80L, 30L, 
10L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, 22L), class = "data.frame")

#data transformations
catvars<-subset(test, 
 select=c(Alcohol,Smoker,CXMP,CXDIAG,Treatment,metformin_base)) #creating new 
 subset of categorical variables that does not include Charlson or BMIfactor

catvars <- catvars %>%
 mutate(across(everything(catvars), factor)) #converting the subset of categorical 
 variables into factors

contvars<-subset(test, select=c(BMI,Waist,age,charleston, 
 FOOD_Fruit,FOOD_Vegetable,exercisemin)) #creating subset of continous variables

contvars <- as.data.frame(lapply(contvars, as.numeric))
```

I have tried all sorts of things- running the loop with the predictors in the same dataframe, running the loop with and without paste0, running the loop with and without as.formula, running the loop with different types of loop functions, running it with different types of anova functions, etc. For the most part, My plan was to run it as a linear model, and then get the summary of results of anova.

```
#linear model
anovas<-for(i in colnames(contvars)) {                           
 for(j in colnames(catvars)) {
 lm(as.formula(paste0(i , "~" , j)), 
 data=cbind(contvars,catvars))
 }
}

#What I plan to use to get the summary once the loop works:
summary(aov(anovas))
```

The loop is what I get stuck on. No matter what I do, it throws an error. And it has thrown many types of errors- extremely large variety. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. With this syntax, the object shows up as "NULL"

Comment: Why do you want to loop? How is that an related to `Anova`?

Comment: I want to loop as my supervisor requested I automate things rather than individually estimate 42 anova models- she wants the syntax to be very clean so that it can then be applied to a larger dataset easily. This has to do with anova because one way to estimate an anova in r is estimate linear models and then ask for a summary of anova results on the models. I got an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

- `cbind()` may be unsafe, `data.frame()` is safer
- the results of a loop are the results of the **last** expression evaluated. You probably need to store the results in a list
- there were a few typos (missing parentheses etc.)
- you could store the results in a *nested list* as in @nrennie's answer, but I felt it would be easier downstream to have them stored in a single *named* list (using `paste(i,j,sep=".")` as the name; I originally did this with a `k` index that I incremented at each step.

```r
combdata <- data.frame(contvars,catvars)
res <- list()
for(i in colnames(contvars)) {                           
    for(j in colnames(catvars)) {
        res[[paste(i,j,sep=".")]] <- lm(as.formula(paste0(i , "~" , j)),
                       combdata)
    }
}
```

You could use something like `sapply(res, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)` to summarize the results.

Comment: I don't understand what the k is doing. Can you clarify that one for me?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a `for` loop to a variable (you need to create an variable somewhere and use the loop to update it), and there are a few brackets missing in your `for` loop.

This will store each of your `lm` models as an element in a list:

```r
anovas <- list()
for(i in colnames(contvars)) {                           
  for(j in colnames(catvars)) {
    anovas[[i]][[j]] <- lm(as.formula(paste0(i , "~" , j)), 
       data=cbind(contvars,catvars))
  }
}
```

You can access the i,j th `lm` model using `anovas[[i]][[j]]`.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the missing parentheses. That was a result of the different variations of the model I attempted, then I forgot to add the parentheses back in when I changed it to colnames. This one returned a list of 0. So I don't think this works. There was another answer provided that worked

Comment: It doesn't return a list of 0 for me when I run it on the data you provided above.

Comment: Just re-ran it. It stopped returning 0.

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: It appears I can only accept one answer. Hmmm. Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Pick whichever one you like best; if it's a tie, @nrennie will benefit more from the extra reputation. You can switch accepted answers if you like.